# cmake for GNU Radio tutorial

Tags: cmake, cppunit, gnuradio

I was trying to follow a tutorial on building the signal processing block on the gnuradio website: http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModules.

However, when it comes to the step where it requires me to use CMake, the terminal is complaining that

```
package cppunit is not found  checking for module 'cppunit'
--   package 'cppunit' not found
-- Could NOT find CPPUNIT (missing:  CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:101 (message):
  CppUnit required to compile howto
```

I have tried command such as `sudo apt-get cppunit`.

Comment: You need the dev package. Try sudo apt-get cppunit-dev.

Comment: @moggi and OP: you mean sudo apt-get **install** cppunit-dev !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need *libcppunit-dev*, which is a library for C++ unit testing:

```
sudo apt install libcppunit-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In fedora, try:

```
sudo dnf install cppunit-devel
```

In ubuntu, try:

```
sudo dnf install cppunit-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

As @moggi mentioned, you need to install the cppunit development package for your distribution.

What's more important, that guide is currently becoming outdated; I'd advise you to follow the new [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials). Also, if you build GNU Radio from source yourself by using [PyBombs](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki), it will a) automatically build the newest and greatest version of GNU Radio from source, and will b) automatically install all the build dependencies for you. Please make sure to uninstall all GNU Radio (and uhd, if any) packages that you've installed using your distribution, first.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Debian, then 
will output usefull info

```
apt-get cache search libcppuint
```

---

```
libcppunit-1.12-1 - Unit Testing Library for C++
libcppunit-subunit-dev - SubunitTestProgressListener for CPPUnit - Development headers
libcppunit-subunit0 - SubunitTestProgressListener for CPPUnit - C++ shared library
libcppunit-1.13-0 - Unit Testing Library for C++
libcppunit-dev - Unit Testing Library for C++
libcppunit-doc - Unit Testing Library for C++
```

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is *very* out of date! I suggest following https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials